# How do I merge values from a list to a list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iteration, nested-lists

I have a a list and a list of lists that look like this

```
groups = ['1','2','3','4','5']

weeks = [['e','e','e','e','e','e','e'],
       ['o','o','m','m','m','o','o'],
       ['l','l','l','l','l','o','o'],
       ['m','m','m','m','m','o','o'],
       ['m', 'm','m','m','m','o','o']]
```

I am able to iterate over the weeks for loop using this code

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(7):
        roster = (weeks[i][j])
        display(roster)
```

But I would like my output to be,

```
e 1
e 1
e 1 ... #for the first row in the weeks list then

o 2 
o 2
m 2 ... #for the next row of the  and so on till it reaches the last row.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pair the items in `groups` with the sub-lists in `weeks` with `zip`:

```
for w, g in zip(weeks, groups):
    for i in w:
        print(i, g)
```

This outputs:

```
e 1
e 1
e 1
e 1
e 1
e 1
e 1
o 2
o 2
m 2
m 2
m 2
o 2
o 2
l 3
l 3
l 3
l 3
l 3
o 3
o 3
m 4
m 4
m 4
m 4
m 4
o 4
o 4
m 5
m 5
m 5
m 5
m 5
o 5
o 5
```

Comment: What way would you recommend to tackle this problem is in the groups list there was more or less values than 5.

Comment: What would your expected output be when there was more or less values than 5 in `groups`?

Comment: I realised that I won't need the question regarding more of less values in my code. But I do have another question, how can I split the list into lets say the third list down so ``` l 3
l 3
l 3
l 3
l 3
o 3
o 3
m 4
m 4
m 4
m 4
m 4
o 4
o 4
m 5
m 5
m 5
m 5
m 5
o 5
o 5 ``` Then start the loop from the beginning, I heard using % is a good idea but im not sure how to execute that

Comment: What do you mean by starting the loop from the beginning?

Comment: after a defined starting point lets say ``` l 3 l 3 l 3 l 3 l 3 o 3 o 3 m 4 m 4 m 4 m 4 m 4 o 4 o 4 m 5 m 5 m 5 m 5 m 5 o 5 o 5 ``` it will start over from ```e 1 e 1 e 1 e 1 e 1 e 1 e 1 ....```  and loop through the list again

Comment: `from itertools import cycle, islice` and then `for w, g in islice(cycle(zip(weeks, groups)), 2, 7):`